# How to search a partial "value" in a map containing String values and Integer keys in Java?

Tags: java, search, dictionary, collections, linked-list

I have below code which I am using for searching a part of "value" in a Map map by converting it into String and using contains() method. The problem is if I search any integer value(e.g "4"), conatins() method returns true because it finds a match with a "key" .

```
 public ArrayList<Map<Integer, String>> search(final ArrayList<Map<Integer, String>> myMapList, String searchTerm)
{
    ArrayList<Map<Integer, String>> newListOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<Integer, String>>();

    for (Map<Integer, String> map : myMapList)
    {
        if (map.toString().contains(searchTerm))
        {
            newListOfMaps.add(map);
        }
    }
    return newListOfMaps;
}
```

Example Data:

- `myMapList.get(0)= {1=laptop, 2=4, 3=stackover, 4=flow}`
- `myMapList.get(1)= {1=laptop, 2=pc, 3=stackover, 4=flow}`

Case 1: If my "searchTerm" is "top", I want both maps returned.

Case 2:If my "searchTerm" is "4", I want only the first map returned.

But I am getting both of them back.

Is there a better way to search in a Map?

Comment: If you convert a Map to string (by calling toString() on it) the returned string will contain both keys and values. Call map.values() to get only values before searching for the target string.

Comment: If you are searching the values, I found that a BiMap comes in handy. You can inverse the map and then use the value as the key. So in your case, map.get(searchTerm) https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have to search each value in each map (unless we are using Java 8 lambda expression, I guess)

```
    public static ArrayList<Map<Integer, String>> search(final ArrayList<Map<Integer, String>> myMapList, String searchTerm)
    {
        ArrayList<Map<Integer, String>> newListOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<Integer, String>>();

        for (Map<Integer, String> map : myMapList)
        {

            for (String value : map.values())
            {
                if (value.contains(searchTerm)){
                    newListOfMaps.add(map);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return newListOfMaps;
    }
}
```

A editable code can be found here : https://ideone.com/0Fs6uG

*Edit* : Using lambda expressions, the entire method can be replaced by either of the following :

```
return myMapList.stream().filter(map -> map.values().toString().contains(searchTerm)).collect(Collectors.toList());

return myMapList.stream().filter(map -> map.values().stream().anyMatch(str -> str.contains(searchTerm))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I would prefer the latter as it would avoid difficulties when the **values** themselves contain commas.